# Generating a simple scene graph for Java game

Tags: java, opengl, scenegraph

I'm working on a relatively simple game in Java using OPENGL (via Processing). I'm using a typical MVC pattern with game updates being passed to the Processing Applet using an Observer pattern. I want to implement a relatively simple scene graph that the model side of the program can update and the view side can read. So far so good but scene graphs are new to me and I'm having trouble coming up with a decent way of generating the scene graph in the first place.

The model side has two collections for game entities at the moment, one for units in the game and a second for environmental objects. I could simply iterate through these and generate nodes to add to the scene graph. What I'm not sure about is what to do when one of these entities is changed or destroyed. Do I generate the entire tree again (seems pretty inefficient) or should each entity `know' its scene node and be able to update it when required?

Does anyone have any general advice or links to material on how to generate the scene graph?

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a connection between graphical object and game entities anyway. Because otherwise you wouldn't be able to translate user event like mouse clicks from scene to logic.

So I would advise to introduce connection between your Model and View. And, IMHO, not by creating a perfect MVC with hiding one from other, as it would add too many hassle on starting stage of development. Just adding a link to graphical object (or, better, interface with actions you want to do with graphic) to game entity should work for you.

It can look like next:

```
interface UnitView {
   void add(Point position);
   void move(Point position);
   void remove(Point position);
   void setOnClick(Runnable callback);
}

class GlUnit implements UnitView extends GLSceneObjectOrWhateverItCalled {
    //this class implements all drawin and animation; and handles calls from model
    //through UnitView interface
}    

class Unit {
    void setView(UnitView view); // this method is called by manager which generated scene

    // here is your implementation of unit logic
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I used a similar solution where each world object knows how to draw itself and generates a scene node that can be added to the tree.